# how to disable lock screen completly from rooted android tablet

Tags: android

I am rooted my China tablet.Now I want to remove lock screen completely means when phone start no lock screen I am trying "No LOck" it disable lock but when I boot phone then lock screen.How can I do this to completely remove lock screen.
Also, I change the boot splash screen and boot animation to my custom splash and custom animation.

Answer (score -1):

Try to edit default.prop file with this parameters:

> ro.secure=0

And in settings menu, setup Lock screen as "None"

Comment: I've done this but "None" option is still missing in my lock screen settings